# Facing issues regarding using datetime/time/varchar datatypes in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, time

I'm currently working on an **Employee leave management system** where I need to handle time duration of **above 24 hours** in sql server and i could not find any solution but to use **varchar** datatype instead of **time/datetime** datatype because **time/datetime** data types has thier limitations.

BUT on the other hand, i also require that particular **varchar** data type column to be used as **datetime** in order to generate reports so **EVENTUALLY** my question is that

Is there any alternative to this situation? Using **varchar** as **time/datetime**? 
A little help would really be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Please provide any example for your situation. A bit unclear...

Comment: You are totally wrong in treating a DateTime as a varchar.  DateTime object when used properly are much better.  Treating DateTime as a varchar has limitations.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your comment. Does datetime store durations above 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, and can handle timezone issues where data is collect from around the world.  Will handle seconds, minutes, day, day of week, years.  It is a double that can handle timespans back to 1/1/1900.

Comment: @jdweng Ah. I certainly didn't know about that. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use BIGINT data type if I **REALLY NEED** to save TimeSpan or duration in the database. It may either be the total number in seconds or ticks, then do the conversion somewhere else (use something like DATEADD function in SQL Server or TimeSpan in C#).

Comment: That is actually a pretty good idea. Lemme try this approach and i'll get back to you here. Thank you!